# Develop Browser Extensions Angular 5/6; Tutorial; Guide

Tags: angular, browser

I would like to ask you a simple but very important question. I have been working recently on a project, where I would like to develop a chrome or browser extension. I would like to use here the Angular Framework, as it's just fantastic and I have been working with it frequently. I would like to develop the extension in Angular and found only 2 interesting tutorials on how to perform this. However, they are mostly outdated. 
I know that I need only the following files at least:

- manifest.json
- index.html (or popup.html)

However, there is still more like the content-script.js or the event page in the background. Angular is in typescript and I have found a gulp taks, that bundles and builds me a single content-script. Anyway I would like to ask you if you have any projects/experience or tutorials and help for developing a browser or chrome extension with Angular 5/6 and the latest CLI and tools?

Comment: I've created chrome extentions. What you have to do is develop the extention as a normal angular app. Then you can build it. After that add manifest.json to the dist folder. 
I follwed [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/chrome-extension-angular-2/)

Comment: https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/build-your-own-chrome-extension-using-angular-4-ecedbd7404cc Helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After project setup these steps you have to follow here.

- Run command “ng build” (lets create you Build for your project in order to publish, this creates dist folder in your project)
- Create manifest.json file in the dist folder. (Basic format given below)

  > ```
  > {
  >  “manifest_version”: 2,
  >  “name”: “ng2 Extension”,
  >  “description”: “Todo app as chrome extension using angular4”,
  >  “version”: “1.0”,
  >  “browser_action”: {
  >  “default_icon”: “icon.png”,
  >  “default_popup”: “index.html”
  >  },
  >  “permissions”: [],
  >  “content_security_policy”: “script-src ‘self’ ‘unsafe-eval’; object-src ‘self’”,
  >  “web_accessible_resources”: [
  >  “assets/css/*”,
  >  “assets/js/*”,
  >  “assets/fonts/*”
  >  ]
  > }
  > ```

For more information read out here -

- [Build Your Own Chrome Extension Using Angular 4](https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/build-your-own-chrome-extension-using-angular-4-ecedbd7404cc)

Comment: Also, check out my article for angular chrome extensions. https://medium.com/@ivansysterov/angular-6-or-ionic-4-chrome-extensions-bc423195cc41